# A good project tree browser for Emacs?

Tags: emacs, project

Do you know of a good project tree browser for Emacs other than the Emacs Code Browser (ECB)? The features I value are simplicity, lightweightedness, and language agnosticism.

Comment: I just decided to start using emacs and already spent like two days trying to find a tree that doesn't suck. I don't understand why none of these packages let you expand entire directory structure and not only first level

Comment: @Agzam, I describe `project-explorer` below, it seems you can completely expand, with `C-u S-TAB`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Speedbar](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/speedbar.shtml)?

If you just want to manage related files, perhaps you would like [eproject](http://github.com/jrockway/eproject).

Comment: I guess I had something like Speedbar in mind when I asked the question. However your eproject might what I was actually looking for without knowing it myself. Currently I rely on iswitch and ibuffer but they tend to become rather congested when working on two or three projects at the same time. Eproject seems to solve that problem.

Comment: speedbar is included by default in emacs 24.

Answer (score 30):

[Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile) + [NeoTree](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NeoTree) are my combination of choice.

[image: Neotree]

Projectile just uses your version control system to track files and has an awesome jump to file in project function.

[image: Projectile]

Also, check [the notes](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NeoTree#toc8) for integrating the two together.

Answer (score 22):

I haven't tried this one myself yet, but [emacs-nav](http://code.google.com/p/emacs-nav/) is a new Emacs project browser from Google that seems to have the features you value.

Comment: I don't really understand nav... it's like sr-speedbar, but without the tree structure. What good is it without the tree structure??

Answer (score 9):

You can try [sr-speedbar](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SrSpeedbar). It's wonderful.

Answer (score 7):

The different parts of [cedet](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/) will do what you want I think.  Speedbar has the tree structure thing, and EDE handles projects etc.

Answer (score 7):

I just now did a word search for "explore" in `package-list-packages`, and discovered `project-explorer`. Seems to fit exactly what I want today (I don't code hardly, but I'm getting a grip on the structure of my Jekyll site).

Keys include:

- `TAB` for folding and unfolding directories
- Open files with `RET` or `f`. With a `C-u` prefix, it will prompt nicely for which window, and even from there allow you to decide to use window or open up a new one to any side (I didn't find the prompt string in the package code, so it seems to leverage built in Emacs functionality nicely; indeed it looks like `dired` even).

It's available on Melpa and Marmalade. It is available on Github at [sabof/project-explorer](https://github.com/sabof/project-explorer).

I include the site's image for convenience:

[image: project-explorer screenshot]

I don't use `projectile` or `helm`, but it has some integration.

Answer (score 6):

Here are my thoughts on several competing file explorer type packages. See the comments above each package below:

```
;; Dired itself allows one to do 'i' to insert (display in same buffer) the
;; subdirectory under point and C-u k on subdir header line to remove. However,
;; I have found that dired-subtree-toggle and dired-subtree-remove are a better solution for the removal
;; part. Plus dired-subtree let's you customize colors of subdirs to set them apart
;; visually. However, I set all depths of subdirectories custom faces to be the same as I found it distracting.
(use-package dired-subtree
  :ensure t
  :bind (:map dired-mode-map ("i" . 'dired-subtree-toggle))
  :bind (:map dired-mode-map ("I" . 'dired-subtree-remove)))


;; This works nicely. It provides the parent, '..', directory unlike nav.
(use-package project-explorer
  :ensure t
  :config
  (evil-set-initial-state 'project-explorer-mode 'emacs))

;; This can't go above the directory you started it in. It is nice, but I prefer the flexibility
;; of getting to parent directories in most cases.
(use-package dirtree
  :ensure t)

;; Google's file explorer
;; Nice, but doesn't maintain visited nodes in view, preferring instead to offer only
;; the current directory or lower in a side window. No better than ivy which is my main file explorer system.
(use-package nav
  :ensure t)

;; This is buggy on Emacs 26.1.
(use-package eproject
  :disabled t
  :ensure t)

;; speedbar is included with Emacs (since 24.x I believe). It has to use a separate frame, which is
;; inconvenient most of the time. There are better options (above).
;; (use-package speedbar)

;; Buggy; doesn't work on Emacs 26.1 (at least with my config).
(use-package sr-speedbar
  :disabled t
  :load-path "../lisp")

;; Buggy on Emacs 26.1 (at least with my config). I couldn't even get it to activate.
(use-package ecb
  :disabled t
  :ensure t)

;; Nice, but similar to ivy which I've already committed to, so not necessary.
(use-package lusty-explorer
  :disabled t
  :ensure t)
```

For me, ivy plus dired gets me 98% of the way. ivy, dired, and dired-subtree gets me 99% of the way. project-explorer, and to a lesser extent, nav, are just nice alternatives to ivy plus dired or ivy plus dired and dired-subtree. Hopefully this will save you some time.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [treemacs](https://github.com/Alexander-Miller/treemacs) and it works well, especially with projectile.

Comment: Treemacs is so cool. It has superseded neotree, which used to be my favorite before Treemacs arrived.

Answer (score 1):

I [found](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/7i3386/yet_another_sidebar_diredsidebar/) [dired-sidebar](https://github.com/jojojames/dired-sidebar) to be fast and awesome, but for some minor inconveniences (icon, few missing commands),
will stay with [Treemacs](https://github.com/Alexander-Miller/treemacs) as my current sidebar.

I don't think I will need Projectile as Emacs 28.1 has greatly improved [project.el](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/progmodes/project.el).
The sidebar and in-built project should be enough.