# Is there something similar for emacs like vims's NERDtree

Tags: file, emacs, project, explorer

For vim there is a filesystem explorer called NERDtree: https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree

Surely an alternative or superior package exists for Emacs?

Comment: you'd reach a much wider audience if you explained what NERDtree does.

Comment: It's a vim plugin, "A tree explorer plugin for navigating the filesystem", see http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658

Comment: how come this question not been flagged?? because its asking for recomendation! but still a very useful one :p

Answer (score 46):

I prefer `dirtree` (screenshot below) by Ye Wenbin. It feels pretty close to NERDTree / the TextMate drawer.

[image: screenshot]

It took me a few minutes of trial and error to figure out the dependencies, so take a look at the install instructions (and a few minor edits to the source) I've got in this [repo](https://github.com/zk/emacs-dirtree).

Comment: how did you get the bar at the bottom that lists the open buffers?

Comment: The bar at the bottom isn't part of Emacs, it's [Tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/), a terminal multiplexer similar to screen.

Comment: Where did you get that theme from?

Comment: I just find it funny that you have a `nsfw` directory there. :)

Answer (score 34):

You can try [NeoTree](https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree) .

https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree

Screenshot:

[image: NeoTree]

Comment: It seems you cannot mark multiple files to do some operations with it in Emacs-neotree, as in Dired.

Answer (score 9):

Have you looked at [Speedbar](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/speedbar.shtml) ?

Answer (score 6):

The [Sunrise Commander](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Sunrise_Commander) seems to be a well written package, and it has a [tree extension](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Sunrise_Commander#toc8).  For a screenshot of the tree extension in action, [follow this link](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SunriseCommanderGraphicalTreeScreenshotPage).

Answer (score 6):

Who needs any tree, when you have the mighty [ido-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings) . If you can train your mind to find the files, rather than just your eyes whilst visually finding it, you will win.  NO need to tell me how biology works, i don't care :-) you get the point.

Comment: `ido-mode` and `projectile` with their fuzzy search are extremely useful when you already know the project you work on and it's file names in particular. But directory tree view is still very helpful when you're just exploring the project and don't know what to search.

Comment: personally if i am 'surfing' my directories i use C+x C+d or dired mode for such things. Or the explorer/Finder which has more helpful 'get to know the environment' gui. or ls -la in terminal. or my grep command in console to grep for an exact match in the files (if needed). The great thing about our linux is there are many ways to skin this cat. I feel you, but I think separating church and state here is a great thing.

Comment: I gotta agree about `ido-mode` and `projectile` but just wanted to throw in `ack-and-a-half` too. With those three I'm more productive than anything while searching through files.

Comment: helm-projectile is also a nice way of quickly finding files in a project.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I prefer the ECB's tree mode.
http://ecb.sourceforge.net/

You should also check out the CEDET stuff.
http://cedet.sourceforge.net/
They contain a lot of other useful stuff that you can use for similar development needs.

Answer (score 3):

I use a little of [emacs-nav](http://code.google.com/p/emacs-nav/) and a little of [dired](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired.html) to navigate my projects' file trees. For file management tasks, I mostly use bash (often from within emacs).

Comment: It depends a lot on what your requirements are of course, but I think dired is better than many people give it credit for. Also, the built-in `dired-x` library with its oh-so-useful `dired-jump` command and binding is disabled by default, which is a shame. See `(info "(dired-x) Miscellaneous Commands")` and `(info "(dired-x) Optional Installation Dired Jump")`

Answer (score 2):

(Shameless reanswer from [A good project tree browser for Emacs? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26705877/2533127))

I just now did a word search for "explore" in `package-list-packages`, and discovered `project-explorer`. Seems to fit exactly what I want today (I don't code hardly, but getting a grip on the structure of my Jekyll site).

Keys include `TAB` for folding and unfolding directories. Open files with `RET` or `f`, but with prefix, it will prompt nicely for which window, and even from there allow you to decide to use window or open up a new one to any side (I didn't find the prompt string in the package code, so it seems to leverage built in Emacs functionality nicely; indeed it looks like `dired` even).

It's available on Melpa and Marmalade, and packaged description points to [sabof_project-explorer · GitHub](https://github.com/sabof/project-explorer).

I include the site's image for convenience:

[image]

I don't use `projectile` or `helm`, but it has some integration.

Answer (score 1):

Try out lusty-explorer. It's a well done plugin.
[Get it here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LustyExplorer)