# Emacs dirtree - Directory tree view setup

Tags: linux, emacs, directory-tree

I am very new to emacs, I am trying to get a directory tree. I have followed another [StackOverFlow Emacs dirtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538064/nerdtree-for-emacs) question and my .emacs and .emacs-d are as follows:

**.emacs**

```lisp
;; line number plugin
(add-to-list 'load-path' "~/.emacs-load-path")
(require 'linum)
(global-linum-mode 1)
;; auto complete plugin
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict")
(ac-config-default)
;; directory tree plugin
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d")
(require 'dirtree)
(require 'tree-mode)
(require 'windata)
(autoload 'dirtree "dirtree" "Add directory to tree view" t)
```

**.emacs.d**

```
dirtree.el
tree-mode.el
windata.el
```

My questions are:

1. Have I set this up correctly, if not, what do I need to do?
2. How do you launch and use dirtree in emacs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tested your setup (as close as I could) and it loads the dirtree functions (and dependencies) fine. The dirtree.el file tries to map Cntl-o (`\C-o`) to `dirtree-display` function but on my system that function fails.

Happily the function `dirtree-show` works fine.  To invoke it manually do:

1. `M-x` (type Alt-x or Esc-x)
2. Type: `dirtree-show`
3. Hit Return
4. It will prompt you for the directory to display - hit Return to show dir of current file
5. The dirtree display will pop up in a frame on the left

Take a look at the "Tree" menu (if you have menus showing in emacs) and it will show you the keystroke shortcuts you can use.  ("e" will toggle expand/collaspe of the current node, for example.)

If you don't want to type `M-x dirtree-show` each time, then you can bind a keystroke to it.  I have bound Cntl-o like this in my .emacs:

```lisp
(global-set-key "\C-o" 'dirtree-show)
```

So my full setup for dirtree is this:

```lisp
(require 'tree-mode)
(require 'windata)
(require 'dirtree)
(autoload 'dirtree "dirtree" "Add directory to tree view" t)
(global-set-key "\C-o" 'dirtree-show)
```

Also, as far I can tell the line `(autoload 'dirtree "dirtree" "Add directory to tree view" t)` isn't required for basic functionality, but perhaps it is needed for some feature I haven't used.

Lastly, just to make sure we are on the same page, I downloaded all the .el files for this from https://github.com/zkim/emacs-dirtree.

Comment: Great answer! That really helped, I have dirtree working now. Thanks for taking the time to test my set up and provide such a detailed answer.

Comment: Glad it worked. Always happy to bring more people into the emacs fold.

Answer (score 5):

Try [NeoTree](https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree). It's easy to install and easy to use.

[image: NeoTree screenshot, from EmacsWiki]

Comment: What's the name of that font, please? It looks so pretty!

Comment: @RnMss Fantasque Sans Mono (source: https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree/issues/97)

Comment: I'm not the only one!